# Include sticky_posts in query but skip X number

Tags: wordpress

So i have this custom query:

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'=>5,
'orderby'=>'date',
'cat'=>'4,6,7,10',
'order'=>'desc',
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

How can i include sticky posts as well, but skip the first 5 sticky posts?

Comment: Oh, wait a minute, are you saying you want to execute this query and add the sixth+ sticky post to it [regaurdless if those posts are in the query], or are you saying you want to exclude the 1st-5th post in that query that happen to be sticky posts? I answered the latter. Anyway, maybe run 2 loops, but you probably want to use the conditional tag "is_sticky()".

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the begging of your loop:

```
if (is_sticky()){
    ++$sticky_posts_counter;
    if ($sticky_posts_counter <= 5){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '++' (T_INC) "